# Remove last / from urls using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to remove the last '/' from all urls using a 301 .htaccess redirect. How would I do it? I have tried the following, but it only removes from the first level of directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[^/]+)/$
RewriteRule . http://www.mysite.net%1 [L,R=301]
```

For example, it works for www.mysite.net/first/ but does not work for www.mysite.net/first/second/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `[^/]+` to just `.+`. The `^/` means "match everything except for a slash", so "first" matches but "first/second" doesn't. Also, you don't need a condition here.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://www.mysite.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```